# How to save Room database data for orientation change

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I create a search actor page where all movie for a specific actor appear using the database. The movies from the database does appear but when I rotate the screen, it disapear. I am trying to save the data using onSaveInstanceState but not sure how to.

Here what i've done so far:

```
var tv4 = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv4)
        var edit1 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edit1)
        var searchActor = findViewById<Button>(R.id.searchActor)

        if (savedInstanceState != null){

        }

        val db = Room.databaseBuilder(this,AppDatabase::class.java,
            "myDatabase").build()

        //Step 2) Create the DAO object of the DB
        val dao = db.getDao()

        searchActor.setOnClickListener {
            runBlocking {
                launch {
                    val allfilm = dao.searchMovie()

                    val actorName = edit1.text.toString().lowercase()
                    tv4.setText("")

                    for (m in allfilm){
                        if (m!!.actor!!.contains(actorName, false))
                        tv4.append(m.title + "\n")

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out `ViewModel`. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

Comment: ViewModel will make this many times easier. Also, never use `runBlocking` in an Android app.